# How do you handle tinyMCE inline mode while building an email template editor?

Tags: jquery, email, templates, tinymce

I'm creating my **own email editor**, I'm using **tinyMCE**. On my page, I therefore have a sidebar with a hundred buttons (image) which correspond to html blocks. when I click on a button, the corresponding code is injected into a large editable textarea with tinyMCE. So I have a big block that looks like what you can see [here](https://nightly.ckeditor.com/latest/standard/ckeditor/samples/): (this one is made with ckeditor but i have something similar).

What I would like ideally is rather something that looks like the "inline" demo visible [here](https://www.tiny.cloud/):

So I have several questions:

Can I insert all the blocks in a styled div, without all the buttons
etc. and make only the blocks themselves editable?

I read [here](https://www.tiny.cloud/blog/email-marketing-software/) that the inline mode did not work on td, and therefore that it is necessary to create div and target an id or a class.

How those who build builder emails proceed ? All email builder (stripo, bee, mozaico, designmodo etc) use inline editing (ckEditor, proprietary solutions or tinyMCE). So do they surround each html component injected in js with a div, and then they remove it when the file is downloaded ? isn't there a simpler way? I can't afford to create hundreds of tinyMCE instances

If anyone has experience in this area, I would appreciate any advice...thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have many div with the same class. For example, we have 4 divs with .email-editable class. All .email-editable elements will have the same options. When you want to save all editors, you need to call tinymce.editors to get the array of Tinymce instances and call save() for each instance:

```js
// create instances of Tinymce for each .email-editable element.
tinymce.init({
  selector: ".email-editable",
  inline: true,
  plugins: "advlist lists link image",
  toolbar: "styleselect | bold italic forecolor | bullist numlist | link image| removeformat",
  menubar: false
});

// this is the action for Click event
// this action will save all editors
document.getElementById('saveB').addEventListener('click', function(){
  // save all editors
  for (var i = 0; i < tinymce.editors.length; i++) {
    tinymce.editors[i].save();
}
  // show html on console
  let html = document.getElementById('email').innerHTML;
  console.log(html);
  // with Jquery:
  // console.log($('#email').html());
});
```

```css
#email-header{
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  color: rgb(64,96,128);
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
}

#email-footer{
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 10px 0;
  color: white;
  background-color: gray;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

.email-editable{
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

#saveB{
  margin-top: 30px;
  padding: 10px 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tinymce/5.6.0/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<div id="email">
  <div id="email-header">Default header (this is not editable)</div>
  <div class="email-editable"><p>CUSTOM CONTENT 1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris a mi libero. Morbi condimentum, <strong>ante non feugiat cursus, sapien ante laoreet turpis, fringilla finibus ante erat quis lorem</strong>. Donec cursus sem eget nunc faucibus semper.</p><ul><li>Item 1</li><li>Item 2</li></ul></div>
  <div class="email-editable"><p>CUSTOM CONTENT 2. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris a mi libero. Morbi condimentum, <strong>ante non feugiat cursus, sapien ante laoreet turpis, fringilla finibus ante erat quis lorem</strong>. Donec cursus sem eget nunc faucibus semper.</p></div>
  <div class="email-editable"><p>CUSTOM CONTENT 3. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris a mi libero. Morbi condimentum, <strong>ante non feugiat cursus, sapien ante laoreet turpis, fringilla finibus ante erat quis lorem</strong>. Donec cursus sem eget nunc faucibus semper.</p></div>
  <div class="email-editable"><p>CUSTOM CONTENT 4. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris a mi libero. Morbi condimentum, <strong>ante non feugiat cursus, sapien ante laoreet turpis, fringilla finibus ante erat quis lorem</strong>. Donec cursus sem eget nunc faucibus semper.</p></div>
  <div id="email-footer">2022 &copy; My Company (this is not editable)</div>
  
</div>
<button id="saveB" type="button">Save email</button>
```

---

**Updated answer**

New template that uses table element. When you click the Save button, then each TD element of tbody will have the content (no DIV) but will lost the TinyMCE editor.

```js
tinymce.init({
  selector: ".email-editable",
  inline: true,
  plugins: "advlist lists link image",
  toolbar: "styleselect | bold italic forecolor | bullist numlist | link image| removeformat",
  menubar: false
});


document.getElementById('saveB').addEventListener('click', function() {
  // obtain all TD elements where you edit the content
  let blocks = document.getElementById('email-body').getElementsByTagName('td');
  // change all inner HTML for each TD element.
  for (var i = 0; i < tinymce.editors.length; i++) {
    let content = tinymce.editors[i].getContent();
    blocks[i].innerHTML = content; // note that this will remove the TinyMCE editor
  }
  // show html on console
  let html = document.getElementById('email').innerHTML;
  console.log(html);
});
```

```css
#email-header {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  color: rgb(64, 96, 128);
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
}

#email-footer {
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 10px 0;
  color: white;
  background-color: gray;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

.email-editable {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

#saveB {
  margin-top: 30px;
  padding: 10px 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tinymce/5.6.0/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<table id="email">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td id="email-header">Default header (this is not editable)</td>
    </tr>
    </thread>
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <td id="email-footer">2022 &copy; My Company (this is not editable)</td>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody id="email-body">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="email-editable">
            <p>CUSTOM CONTENT 1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris a mi libero. Morbi condimentum, <strong>ante non feugiat cursus, sapien ante laoreet turpis, fringilla finibus ante erat quis lorem</strong>. Donec cursus sem
              eget nunc faucibus semper.</p>
            <ul>
              <li>Item 1</li>
              <li>Item 2</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="email-editable">
            <p>CUSTOM CONTENT 2. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris a mi libero. Morbi condimentum, <strong>ante non feugiat cursus, sapien ante laoreet turpis, fringilla finibus ante erat quis lorem</strong>. Donec cursus sem
              eget nunc faucibus semper.</p>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="email-editable">
            <p>CUSTOM CONTENT 3. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris a mi libero. Morbi condimentum, <strong>ante non feugiat cursus, sapien ante laoreet turpis, fringilla finibus ante erat quis lorem</strong>. Donec cursus sem
              eget nunc faucibus semper.</p>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="email-editable">
            <p>CUSTOM CONTENT 4. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris a mi libero. Morbi condimentum, <strong>ante non feugiat cursus, sapien ante laoreet turpis, fringilla finibus ante erat quis lorem</strong>. Donec cursus sem
              eget nunc faucibus semper.</p>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>


</table>
<button id="saveB" type="button">Save email</button>
```

Comment: thank again Nonameyet..so as we need clean html (only table etc) how do you do when you export your html file ? you dynamicaly delete all those div that are not useful anymore ? for me it can be a problem as div can break the layout sometime and for example in a bloc if you need to only make a title editable, that mean you have to put div in many different places, at different level..I could just make the whole file editable, which is less sexy and more error-prone..it's a huge job if you have hundreds of blocks!!

Comment: I have updated the answer and changed the template.

Comment: incredible, thank you very much nonameyet. I try to mix your answers to find the best way of achieve this project. At the begining I was using 'tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent(code);' to inject all my code in a textarea so the whole bloc was editable. Now as I want to edit inner content, I have to add the content on click in a normal div and apply tinymce only to inner content block..so I have to rebuild everything. But your answers are very helpful, thanks again for you kind help !

Comment: by the way, is there a reason why you're using a save function ? because in my case, I just need a blank div, inject code inside it, edit it and then export..maybe I'm wrong but I don't need to save anything right ?

Comment: You are right. It is only an example. Use it if you want.

Comment: finaly the last solution to delete all tinymce instances and style doens't work for me.I created a new question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72552522/how-can-i-delete-all-tinymce-styles-and-div-when-downloading-my-file with another file..