# Email editor with tinymce : how to export a clean html file?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, tinymce

I managed to create an email editor, modeled on [this example](https://www.tiny.cloud/blog/email-marketing-software/). At the end of the file I add a **download button**, so that the user can retrieve the file he edited.

My problem is that tinymce injects a lot of code, tag, class,attributes and id that I would like to remove during export. Is there a function or plugin that can retrieve its file without any reference to tinymce ?

for the moment I delete each element "manually" which does not seem to me at all optimal. There are too many elements (attributes among others everywhere) and I'm sure there is an easier way..

```js
document.getElementById('btnHtml').addEventListener('click', function() {

  let $email = $('.email-container');
  let contentToDelete = document.querySelectorAll("script,div.mce-tinymce,#mceDefaultStyles,.mce-widget,#u0,#u1,button");//
  contentToDelete.forEach((element) => element.remove());//remove all elements and children that are outside tinymce editors

  // Get content from all editors 
  for (var i = 0; i < tinymce.editors.length; i++) {
    let editable = $email.find('.content')[i];
    editable.innerHTML = tinymce.editors[i].getContent();
    editable.removeAttribute('spellcheck');
    // If you remove "contenteditable" then this node will not open TinyMCE when you click on it.
    editable.removeAttribute('data-mce-bogus');
    editable.removeAttribute('data-mce-style');
    editable.removeAttribute('[data-mce-href');
    editable.classList.remove('mce-content-body');
    editable.classList.remove('mce-item-table');
   
  
  }

      var txtboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.content');
      txtboxes.forEach(box => {
      box.replaceWith(...box.childNodes);//remove only  div.content itself not the children
    });
   
       
  let full = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(document.doctype);//serialize all the document, get the doctype
  let innercontent = document.documentElement.outerHTML;
  let content = full + innercontent; // append doctype to html content
  let blob = new Blob([content], {
    type: 'text/html'
  });

  // Create download link and then download.
  const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  const a = document.createElement("a");
  a.download = "index.html";
  a.style.display = 'none';
  a.href = url;
  //document.body.appendChild(a);

  // this link will not work here so try it on "codepen.io" or on your computer
  a.click();

  // Release object URL
  window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
});
```

```html
//at the end of my html file
  <button type="button" id="btnHtml" type="button">Download html file</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Is there a function or plugin that can retrieve its file without any reference to tinymce ?*

Yes, the function is `getContent`. I can show you an example using jQuery 3.6.0 and TinyMCE 5.6.0:

```js
// create instances of Tinymce for each .email-editable element.
tinymce.init({
  selector: ".email-editable",
  inline: true,
  plugins: "advlist lists link image",
  toolbar: "styleselect | bold italic forecolor | bullist numlist | link image| removeformat",
  menubar: false,
});

document.getElementById('save').addEventListener('click', function() {

  let $email = $('#email');

  // Get content from all editors 
  for (var i = 0; i < tinymce.editors.length; i++) {
    let editable = $email.find('.email-editable')[i];
    editable.innerHTML = tinymce.editors[i].getContent();
    editable.removeAttribute('spellcheck');

    // If you remove "contenteditable" then this node will not open TinyMCE when you click on it.
    editable.removeAttribute('contenteditable');
    editable.classList.remove('mce-content-body');

    // Note that the "getContent" function omits the TinyMCE metadata. Try it with "console.log". ;-)
    console.log(tinymce.editors[i].getContent());
  }

  // For this example, serialize only the #email element and their children
  let emailContent = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString($('#email')[0]);
  let blob = new Blob([emailContent], {
    type: 'text/html'
  });

  // Create download link and then download.
  const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  const a = document.createElement("a");
  a.download = "index.html";
  a.style.display = 'none';
  a.href = url;
  //document.body.appendChild(a);

  // this link will not work here so try it on "codepen.io" or on your computer
  a.click();

  // Release object URL
  window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
});
```

```css
#email-header {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  color: rgb(64, 96, 128);
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
}

#email-footer {
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 10px 0;
  color: white;
  background-color: gray;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

.email-editable {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

#save {
  margin-top: 30px;
  padding: 10px 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.special {
  color: #7ae;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tinymce/5.6.0/tinymce.min.js"></script>

<div id="email">
  <div id="email-header">Unmodifiable header :)</div>
  <div class="email-editable">Insert your text here</div>
  <div class="email-editable">
    <ul>
      <li>Some text and more text...</li>
      <li><span class="special">Special item</span> for you.</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="email-footer">2022 &copy; Unmodifiable footer :)</div>

</div>
<button id="save" type="button">Export to html</button>
```

Note that I only remove the attributes of containers (i mean `.email-editable` elements) that TinyMCE has generated for me in my example, so you can remove other attributes too. I don't use `tinymce.editors[i].save();` because it adds the metadata of Tinymce. This metadata is useful for editing the text in the future. For instance, you can store the text in a database and then retrieve it for further editing.

Also note that I use `URL.revokeObjectURL`. From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/revokeObjectURL:

> *Call this method when you've finished using an object URL to let the browser know not to keep the reference to the file any longer.*

---

> *for the moment I delete each element "manually" which does not seem to me at all optimal. There are too many elements (attributes among others everywhere) and I'm sure there is an easier way..*

You are doing right. Another way is by extending the jQuery object to add a function. On the web page https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-remove-all-attributes-of-an-html-element-using-jquery/ you have an example to add a function that removes all the attributes of a node. Perhaps you can edit that function to add a whitelist (an array of strings) as an input parameter.

The sample code (credits to GeeksForGeeks.org) is:

```js
$.fn.removeAllAttributes = function() {
    return this.each(function() {
        $.each(this.attributes, function() {
            this.ownerElement.removeAttributeNode(this);
        });
    });
};

$('textarea').removeAllAttributes();
```

---

## UPDATE

> *if I add a specific class for each editor, in order to give them different options, with this code my logo is repeated 3 times, and my first block of text disappears.. do you know how to correctly retrieve the content with different classes ? I tried with ids, I have the same problem. let editable = $email.find('.logo, .banner, .fragment,.content')[i]; editable.innerHTML = tinymce.editors[i].getContent();*

Assign each editor a unique id. The TinyMCE API has the function `tinymce.get(id)` (see [reference](https://www.tiny.cloud/blog/get-tinymce-by-element-selector/)) that returns a specific editor, so my new example is...

```js
// create instances of Tinymce for elements #logo, #banner, #fragment and #content.
tinymce.init({
  selector: "#logo",
  inline: true,
  plugins: "advlist lists link image",
  toolbar: "styleselect | bold italic forecolor",
  menubar: false,
});
tinymce.init({
  selector: "#banner",
  inline: true,
  plugins: "advlist lists link image",
  toolbar: "styleselect | bold italic forecolor | bullist numlist | link image| removeformat",
  menubar: false,
});
tinymce.init({
  selector: "#fragment",
  inline: true,
  plugins: "advlist lists link image",
  toolbar: "styleselect | bullist numlist | link image| removeformat",
  menubar: false,
});
tinymce.init({
  selector: "#content",
  inline: true,
  plugins: "advlist lists link image",
  toolbar: "styleselect | bullist numlist | link image| removeformat",
  menubar: false,
});

document.getElementById('saveB').addEventListener('click', function() {
  let $email = $('#email');

  $("#logo").html(tinymce.get("logo").getContent());
  $("#banner").html(tinymce.get("banner").getContent());
  $("#fragment").html(tinymce.get("fragment").getContent());
  $("#content").html(tinymce.get("content").getContent());

  // Clean containers
  $('#logo, #content, #fragment, #banner')
    .removeAttr('spellcheck')
    .removeAttr('contenteditable')
    .removeClass('mce-content-body');

  // For this example, serialize only the #email element and their children
  let emailContent = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString($('#email')[0]);
  let blob = new Blob([emailContent], {
    type: 'text/html'
  });

  // Create download link and then download.
  const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  const a = document.createElement("a");
  a.download = "index.html";
  a.style.display = 'none';
  a.href = url;
  //document.body.appendChild(a);

  // this link will not work here so try it on "codepen.io" or on your computer
  a.click();

  // Release object URL
  window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
});
```

```css
#email-header {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  color: rgb(64, 96, 128);
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
}

#email-footer {
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 10px 0;
  color: white;
  background-color: gray;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

.email-editable {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

#saveB {
  margin-top: 30px;
  padding: 10px 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.special {
  color: #7ae;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tinymce/5.6.0/tinymce.min.js"></script>

<div id="email">
  <div id="email-header">Unmodifiable header :)</div>
  <div id="logo">Insert <span style="color:red">your logo</span> here...</div>
  <div id="banner">Add some banner here...</div>
  <div id="fragment">Add <strong>some text</strong> here...</div>
  <div id="content">Insert your content here</div>
  <div id="email-footer">2022 &copy; Unmodifiable footer :)</div>

</div>
<button id="saveB" type="button">Export to html</button>
```

Comment: Hello Nonameyet! thanks a lot for your clear and detailed answer. I edited my answer using your code, which seems to me cleaner. There are just fiew extra tinymce code outside the editors that I needed to remove too, and for the "txtboxes" variable part, I don't know how to merge it in your function, so I kept it as it was and added it outside the foreach function.  Thank you very much for your help !

Comment: if I add a specific class for each editor, in order to give them different options, with this code my logo is repeated 3 times, and my first block of text disappears.. do you know how to correctly retrieve the content with different classes ? I tried with ids, I have the same problem.

let editable = $email.find('.logo, .banner, .fragment,.content')[i];
    editable.innerHTML = tinymce.editors[i].getContent();

Comment: Ok, give me a moment :-)

Comment: New example at the end

Comment: thank you very much Nonameyet..strangly, it works with your example, but when I try to adapt it to mine, it throws me errors..I have to investigate..I read on many threads that in case of ID, we can just use for (i=0; i < tinyMCE.editors.length; i++){
    var content = tinyMCE.editors[i].getContent();
    alert('Editor-Id(' + tinyMCE.editors[i].id + '):' + content);
} without defining each editors..anyway I have to investigate to find where the errors come from..thanks again :)

Comment: if I replicate the code on my side I have an error : Uncaught TypeError: $(...).removeAttribute is not a function
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous>

Comment: ok finaly it's working..you solved my problem, thank you very very much !!..I'm mixing javascript and jquery objects but nomatter, I'll try to fix this later..I have others issue, I don't know if you have already encounter that and have time/can have solution for this too ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72580446/why-tinymce-removes-some-of-my-inline-style

Comment: `element.removeAttribute('my-attr')` in Javascript and `$('selector').removeAttr('my-attr')` in Jquery.

Comment: yes I saw that and corrected my code..thank  you very much