# Why Tinymce removes some of my inline style?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, tinymce, tinymce-plugins

I'm using tinymce on an email template. Here is an example of the template I add through the template plugin. (see below)

1-The issue is that tinymce deletes the background-color of the first level td and I don't understand why..If I add the background-color on the next table tag, it works. As I don't want to change all my templates, what is the best way to allow background color and other css properties on td ? I tried class="mceTmpl" on the tr or td, it doesn't change anything.

```
<tr>
   <td>
    <div class="content">
     <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%" style="margin: auto;">
      <tr>
        <td align="center"  style="font-size:0;background-color: #23004C;">
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" role="presentation" style="width:100%;font-size:0;line-height:0;">
                <tr>
                    <td align="left" valign="top" dir="rtl">
```

And here is what I get. It's removing a entire tr >  td > table

```
<tr>
     <td>
       <div class="content mce-content-body" id="mce_3" contenteditable="true" spellcheck="false">
         <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" role="presentation" style="width: 100%; font-size: 0; line-height: 0;" data-mce-style="width: 100%; font-size: 0; line-height: 0;" class="mce-item-table">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td align="left" valign="top" dir="rtl">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT AND ANSWER:** finaly the only solution I found was to modify the begining of my template, following the docs. Instead of starting directly with a tr>td I add a div with the mceTmpl class, and then a table tag:

```
<div class="mceTmpl"><table role="presentation" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="680">
```

and in the html file to create the space where the template should be called, I removed the table tag and replaced it by a div with the selector Id :

```
<tr>
   <td>
    <div id="banner"  role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%" style="margin: auto;"></div>                
   </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: thanks a lot nonameyet..I don't understand because I tried the code you provided, which for me is the copy of the tinymce example, so don't really understand because I don't see how to adapt it to my specific case with the "template" plugin. I tried the document.ready option around all my js functions, like in the example, but it doesn't change. The code is always modified and the background color does not show up, unless I modify the code as in my answer added above..
anyway, thank you very much because your answer might always help people who are working on this kind ot thing..